# StackOverflowError when keybord is dismissed

Tags: java, android

I have an custom view that is extended from MultiAutoCompleteTextView to create chiped view like contacts in gmail. when i a contact to this view and the keyborad is dismissed it casuse stack overflow. it happens only in my nexus 4 this is the logcat.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
            at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
            at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6134)
            at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6032)
            at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6571)
            at android.widget.TextView.onRtlPropertiesChanged(TextView.java:8672)
            at android.view.View.resolvePadding(View.java:12407)
            at android.view.View.getPaddingLeft(View.java:15603)
            at com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView.maxTextWidth(TokenCompleteTextView.java:260)
            at com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView.access$1000(TokenCompleteTextView.java:54)
            at com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView$ViewSpan.prepView(TokenCompleteTextView.java:822)
            at com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView$ViewSpan.getSize(TokenCompleteTextView.java:841)
            at com.tokenautocomplete.TokenCompleteTextView$TokenImageSpan.getSize(TokenCompleteTextView.java:885)
```

this is my prep view code

```
private void prepView() {
        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)maxTextWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

this is line 260 of tokenCompleteTextView

```
private float maxTextWidth() {
    return getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
}
```

is use [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete) libray for the token view.

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/gray" 
android:clickable="true">

 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/llsearch"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
 android:orientation="horizontal"   
 android:weightSum="4"      
 android:background="@color/listview_color"
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hdpi_4dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/hdpi_4dp"
 android:gravity="center_vertical">

 <in.ispg.chipview.ConatctCompleteTextView
 android:id="@+id/edtsearch"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="@string/search"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_edittext"
 android:textColor="@color/black"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/hdpi_4dp"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/hdpi_4dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hdpi_8dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hdpi_8dp"
 android:singleLine="false"
 android:minLines="1"
 android:maxLines="5"
 >
    <requestFocus />
</in.ispg.chipview.ConatctCompleteTextView>


<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnsearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/hdpi_33dp"
    android:text="@string/done"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@drawable/send_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hdpi_8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
```

```
<in.ispg.utils.FontTextView 
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_edittext"
android:textColor="#595959"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:text="" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable ="@drawable/progress"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

**Note**

I know how to dismiss the keyboard. that is not my problem. I get a stackoverflow error when i do so in a specific view.

Comment: Do you have a `TextWatcher` on the `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: yes there is a `textWatcher` on `AutocomplereTextview` that loads data `afterTextChanged`

Comment: Could you show me the code of that `TextWatcher`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VXfjT0bB this the textwatcher

Comment: Edit the code into your question. Don't link to it.

Comment: Do you call `setText()` on the `AutocomplereTextview` somewhere?

Comment: setText is not called. but i am changing the items in the list that is used in the dropdown. This happens only in my nexus 4 device.

Comment: What are you doing here: `view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);` and here `view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());`?

Comment: it is from a library that i am using called tokenautocomplete http://goo.gl/ynql6W

Comment: I suggest you just try to debug this until you find the source of the error. Look at the stack trace. It tells you which methods are calling each other continuously, it's basically just an infinite loop that never gets broken until the stack is full hence the `StackOverflowError`. Place brake point somewhere in there and then just debug step by step until you find the reason this is behaving as it is. If you cannot find the error, then you are going to have to find another library.

Comment: private static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, View v) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
        .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

try this

Comment: Post the code or xml where you used this custom view

Comment: Did you solve it? I've got the same problem here

Comment: @msander no, i just handled it in a try catch.

Answer (score 0):

1.) try this , hope it will solve your issue, i use the below code to HideSoftkeyboard

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()
            .getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

OR

If I need to care about when the keyboard appears and disappears (which is quite often) then what I do is customize my top-level layout class into one which overrides onMeasure(). The basic logic is that if the layout finds itself filling significantly less than the total area of the window, then a soft keyboard is probably showing.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Rect;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
```

/*
 * LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard - a variant of LinearLayout that can detect when 
 * the soft keyboard is shown and hidden (something Android can't tell you, weirdly). 
 */

```
public class LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard extends LinearLayout {

public LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public interface Listener {
    public void onSoftKeyboardShown(boolean isShowing);
}
private Listener listener;
public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int statusBarHeight = rect.top;
    int screenHeight = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    int diff = (screenHeight - statusBarHeight) - height;
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onSoftKeyboardShown(diff>128); // assume all soft keyboards are at least 128 pixels high
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);       
}

}
```

Then in your Activity class...

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements      LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard.Listener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard mainLayout = (LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard)findViewById(R.id.main);
    mainLayout.setListener(this);
    ...
}


@Override
public void onSoftKeyboardShown(boolean isShowing) {
    // do whatever you need to do here
}

 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to hide soft keyboard

// To close the soft keyboard

```
InputMethodManager inputMethod = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethod.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why it happens. I tested in differents devices and in a emulator. This error happens just in some devices and in emulator I can't simulate it. This is what I did:

```
@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        try{
            prepView();
        }catch(StackOverflowError error){

        }
        ...
```

This code prevent the application close.

Comment: This is actually not always true. Catching an error (vs an exception) will most likely just cause your app to behave in unexpected ways (and probably still crash).